# How many UART interfaces can be used in this MCU

Tags: microcontroller, digital-logic, uart, serial, digital-communications

I want to understand how many UART interfaces can I use in this [ATSAMD21 MCU](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/MCU32/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/SAM-D21-DA1-Family-Data-Sheet-DS40001882H.pdf).

I searched for "UART" in the datasheet to find which pins and how many UART interfaces I can connect to. But I didn't get exact "UART" matches. Only "USART" matches are coming.

Can someone help me how to find the pins that support the UART interface?

Also, each UART interface (peripheral) requires 2 separate lines from the MCU, right?

Comment: A USART is usable as a UART as well; otherwise, it would just be a USRT.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Six

From page 2 in the datasheet:

> Up to six Serial Communication Interfaces (SERCOM), each configurable to operate as either:
>
> - USART with full-duplex and single-wire half-duplex configuration
> - [...things we don't care about]

Not all MCUs in the D21 series can use all six. There is a detailed table in chapter 2 listing product-specific data such as RAM size and pin count, but also the number of SERCOM peripherals. Some have four, but most have six.

Additionally, chapter 7 of the datasheet tells us that each of SERCOM's four configurable pins can be mapped out to a unique I/O on the MCU, and I think have a unique DMA channel. Technically you only need one line for UART if you only need to transmit *or* receive data, but normally you want both TX and RX.

You won't be able to use SPI or I2C with all six UART in use.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 1. So, you mean to say, I can use six separate TX and RX pins as UART from the MCU right? 2. But UART is different from USART right? I can use USART as UART?

Comment: @Freshman **U**niversal **S**ynchronous _and **A**synchronous_ **R**eceiver and **T**ransmitter. It's not different, it's just more flexible.

Answer (score 2):

When looking up things like this, the first thing you need to settle is the package. Are you using the maximum pin count one (likely some LQFP or BGA) or a reduced size one (likely some QFN or BGA). The maximum number of peripherals available usually assumes the largest package.

There will be a table in the Friendly Manual explaining such. And indeed it took me less than 5 seconds to locate this table: **chapter 2, configuration summary**. Just read it. Also chapter 3 about ordering information and part numbers. The info required is pretty much rubbed in the reader's face, impossible to miss.

From there make a plan for which MCU package and possible pin-outs that would work for your use-case. The MCU will share these pins/peripherals with other features.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am just a beginner. I searched specifically for I2C, UART, SPI etc. But I confused. I didnt think SERCOM peripheral support all these interfaces.

Comment: @Freshman It's microcontroller vendor tradition to give the various serial peripherals some dumb, unhelpful name out of prestige or perhaps once because of active patents. UART was invented by National semi back in the Jurassic period somewhere, and their competitors wouldn't like acknowledge that name, so they tend to call it something completely unhelpful instead. Same thing with SPI, only Motorola who invented it actually called it SPI. Others would call UART or SPI Serial-something-something. Whereas real-world engineers always call these UART, SPI and I2C respectively.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. So, I now understand that all six peripherals of SERCOM can be used as I2C, SPI, or UART/USART.

Comment: @Freshman If you use the 48 or 64 pin versions, yes. Otherwise, only 4.